# Reaction of formic acid with bridged bicyclic compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

> Write the mechanism for:
>
> [image: question]

I've been able to add part of the product, but am having trouble with the ring formation. Here is my attempt:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the adjacent methyl groups attached to the bicyclo[2.2.2]octane. Can you spot the pattern in the product? When the free $\ce{OH}$ is esterified, what happens to the bridgehead methoxy group under acidic conditions?

Comment: Could come up with uploadable picture?

Comment: @klauswarzecha I don't know if you saw my second picture, but I've already added the formic acids to the methyls and etherified the OH, is there any way I can form a ring with that carbocation? Or am I going about it all wrong?

Comment: Maybe start by looking up named sigmatropic rearrangements. That should help get you started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I leave the arrows filling and details of last step to you since it is homework and online Marvin JS did not let me do arrows the way I liked to.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This calligraphy might show you the direction.

[image]